# Copy selected List-Items to an other list with ECMA Script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i need a script that copies all my selected list items to an other (custom) list. I found nice solution for documents:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
context.load(web);

var _destinationlib = web.get_lists().getByTitle('DestinationLibrary');
context.load(_destinationlib);
var notifyId;
var currentlibid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();

var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentlibid);

var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var count = CountDictionary(selectedItems);

for(var i in selectedItems)
{
 alert('Now copying ' + i);
 var currentItem =    currentLib.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
 context.load(currentItem);

var File = currentItem.get_file();
context.load(File);

//Excecuting executeQueryAsync to get the loaded values
context.executeQueryAsync
(
function (sender, args) {
if(File != null) {

var _destinationlibUrl =  web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + _destinationlib.get_title() + '/' +  File.get_name();

File.copyTo(_destinationlibUrl, true);
notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Moving file…' + File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + 'to' + _destinationlibUrl, true);

//Excecuting executeQueryAsync to copy the file
context.executeQueryAsync(
function (sender, args) {
SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);

SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('File copied successfully', false);
},
function (sender, args) {
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Error copying file', false);
SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notifyId);
showError(args.get_message());
});
}
},
function (sender, args) {
alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
}
);
}
```

I dont know what i have to change to get it working for normal list items.  I tried to exchange

```
var File = currentItem.get_file();

context.load(File);
```

with

```
var title = currentItem.get_Title();
context.load(title);

var number = currentItem.get_item('number');
context.load(number);
```

but it dosnt work. It would be great if somebody can give me a hint what i have to do.

many thx

Fabulus

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you took code above from [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/28/sharepoint-2010-ecmascript-copymove-files-to-another-document-library-part-2/).

Try to be attentively. This code copies selected files (not list items!) to another document library!

For your needs better try to code your own solution. See [SharePoint JavaScript Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253) for details. You can have two possible architectures:

1. Make all work from JavaScript.  And the first your step will be [addItem method of SP.List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658490).
2. Make processing of selection on client in JavaScript and call your custom server-side component (may be an application page) for items copying (creating copies in new list of already existed items from initial list.). See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400720/SharePoint-2010-Export-Selected-Items-to-Excel) for example.

Also be careful with context.load. It's recommended to write all next code in context.executeQueryAsync. Use Firebug in FF and developer tools in Chrome for debugging your code and to find what is wrong.